# How to use FCM as push notification and Google as analytic

Tags: objective-c, google-analytics, firebase-cloud-messaging

Can i used google analytics and firebase Cloud Messaging at one time?

Currently i used different account for those 2, and i found that, that 2 services used 2 different GoogleService-info.plist too.

Can i used 2 different GoogleService-info.plist at 1 apps? and how to solve it?

Thanks for the help.